# Boolean Algebra And DeMorgan Laws

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic

I am trying to find the complement of a function: `X(Y+Z!W+!VS)` utilizing DeMorgan's laws.

I also need to express the result as a Sum Of Products.

I think the complement should be: `!X + (Y!(Z+!W)(V!S))` But I'm not sure...

And then even if I am I'm uncertain how to get this into Sum Of Product Form.

Thoughts?

Comment: `a(b+c)` = `ab + ac`, `!(ab)` = `!a + !b`, `!(a+b)` = `!a!b`. It can't be that difficult to apply those laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ![X(Y+Z!W+!VS)]
= ![XY + XZ!W + X!VS]                                  distributive law
= !(XY)!(XZ!W)!(X!VS)                                  De Morgan's law
= (!X+!Y)(!X+!Z+W)(!X+V+!S)                            De Morgan's law
= (!X!X+!X!Z+!X!W+!Y!X+!Y!Z+!YW)(!X+V+!S)              distributive law
= (!X+!Y!Z+!YW)(!X+V+!S)                               x OR (x AND y) = x
= !X!X+!XV+!X!S+!Y!Z!X+!Y!ZV+!Y!Z!S+!YW!X+!YWV+!YW!S   distributive law
= !X+!Y!ZV+!Y!Z!S+!YWV+!YW!S                           x OR (x AND y) = x
```

This is in sum-of-products form. Taking it a bit further...

```
= !X+!Y(!Z+W)(V+!S)                                    distributive law
```

Comment: I'm quite against doing other people's homework to this extent.

Comment: @Dukeling Out of curiosity, why? I'll ignore for the moment that we're assuming guilt without any reasonable proof.

Comment: Because people usually learn very little when you give them an out-of-the-box answer. I'd rather just point them in the right direction. If it's an algorithmic challenge, it's a different story (for me).

Comment: @Dukeling This might sound dismissive, but why should you or I care about whether ZAX learns anything? That's ZAX's responsibility.

Comment: Help those who try to help themselves, or something like that. Time spent answering this question *probably* would've been better spent helping someone with a different question who has shown some attempt at solving it, because it is *more likely* that they would try to understand the answer rather than mindlessly copying/pasting it. But to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

To implement DeMorgans, it's often easiest to break things into small parts

```
result=!(XA),    (A= Y+Z!W+!VS) Simplify!
!X + !A                   DeMorgans
A = Y+B      (B= Z!W+!VS) Simplify!
!A = !Y!B                 DeMorgans
B= C+D     (C= Z!W     D= !VS) Simplify!
!B = !C!D                  DeMorgans
!C = !Z+W                 DeMorgans
!D = V+!S                 DeMorgans
!B = (!Z+W)(V+!S)         Put it back together!
!A = !Y(!Z+W)(V+!S)
result = !X+!Y(!Z+W)(V+!S)
```

To get it into [Sum of Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_%28Boolean_algebra%29), requires a bit more algebra.

```
 !X already ok
 + !Y(!Z+W)(V+!S)             not ok, let's call it !Y!B again.
 !B= (!Z+W)(V+!S)             remember this?
 !B= !ZV+!Z!S+WV+W!S          distribute!
 -> !X + !Y(!ZV+!Z!S+WV+W!S)  put it back together... still not quite right
 !X + !Y!ZV + !Y!Z!S + !YWV + !YW!S    distribute again!
```

And now we have a Sum of Products:
 !X + !Y!ZV + !Y!Z!S + !YWV + !YW!S